# Is it possible to automatically backup a mysql database to dropbox?

Tags: mysql, database, backup

Is it possible to automatically backup my database to dropbox? If so how can I do it?

The key criteria I need it to do is:

1. Be automatic.
2. Be Mac compliant.
3. Be weekly.
4. Sync with dropbox (http://www.dropbox.com) automatically.
5. Be able to backup several databases from several websites.
6. Be free... or relatively cheap!
7. Have a guide on how to setup the solution.

UPDATE:

I've managed to setup an auto weekly backup using a cronjob:

```
mysqldump -u username -pMyPassword Mydatabase > backup-file.sql
```

That is saving the backup to my hosting space. It's a start but isn't ideal, how can I save that backup to a folder on my computer? Automatically of course.

Comment: MySql Backup FTP (http://mysqlbackupftp.com/) creates remote MySQL database backups,
Zips, Encrypts and sends backups to a folder, FTP, Dropbox, Box, Google Drive, MS OneDrive, Amazon S3 or Windows Azure Storage. Buy the Way it is free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean "mac-compliant"? If you want to run it on the mac (or linux), you should just make a weekly cronjob that runs `mysqldump` and stores output into your dropbox directory. The latter would require installing the dropbox daemon.

Comment: As in I/we use Mac computers, therefore the solution needs to be performed on a Mac. How would I do that? I have no experience in cronjobs and my mysql knowledge is limited at best.

Comment: You go to the terminal and type `man crontab` and `man mysqldump`. The crontab will turn out to be something like `0 0 * * Sun mysqldump... >Dropbox/backup.sql` and the `...` part you should really look up in the mysqldump manpage, there are many options most of which you can omit, but better get acquainted with.

Comment: Ok will do. Would a cronjob be the only option to do this?

Comment: Maybe there are other schedulers available, but this is the only standard I know of.

Comment: Ok I'm starting to get somewhere, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I've setup a cronjob that's backing up the database weekly, this is saving to my hosting space. It's not ideal so is there a way to auto save the file to a folder on my computer (dropbox will handle the rest).

Comment: I'm confused, do you have a mac-based hosting?

Comment: No I just don't think I understood the whole process!

Comment: So, I take it your procedure is not to be fully performed on mac then. Then you can either `scp` files to your mac, or you can install dropbox daemon on your linux and stream backup into dropbox folder. Honestly, I have never installed dropbox on a headless machine, but I know it's possible.

Comment: It needs to be automatic, that's kinda the whole point of the process. It doesn't really matter how it's done as long as I can auto backup the database out of my web hosting.

Comment: Again, you *can* run, for instance, cronjob on your machine that `scp`s the backup from he server (that would require your machine to be on at that time). And you can set up the dropbox folder on your linux and it will be automatically synchronized with dropbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this bash script called [Dropbox-Uploader](https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader)

Answer (score 0):

There is a full tutorial on how to do this here: [Database Backup using dropbox](http://www.inkhorn.ca/mysql-database-backups-using-dropbox-2/)

Answer (score -1):

you could check out a service like https://mybackupbox.com/ - which is free for smaller transfers.